# What is the significance of component ?

Tags: character-components

This component shows up as a component of both 隠 and 穏. What is the significance of this component?

Comment: 㥯 (also written as ) (yǐn; cautious) is just a sound component in both of these characters, meaning all this component does is give the pronunciation to the character.

Comment: Note that we use 「㥯」 in Chinese; 「」 is from a Japanese standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern Chinese language, 隠 and 穏 are "錯字(Wrong word)", the concept of 錯字 equals [misspelling(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling#Misspellings) , But these are also [Variant_Chinese_characters(異體字)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_characters) and judging by existing records,  is a 異體字 of [急(quick)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%80%A5).

Now let us talk about ["隱"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9A%B1) and ["穩"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A9%A9).

The meaning of [㥯(/ yin3 /)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%A5%AF) is careful, worried...and so on.

[Shuo Wen Jie Zi] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) said, For 隱, [阝](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%98%9D) (異體字 of [阜](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%98%9C)) to show meaning(significance component), and 㥯 to show pronunciation(sound component). So is 隱 is /ying3/, and its meaning is that the huge shelter(wall, mountain) obstruct the view. So the sb./sth is hidden.

As to 穩, its significance component is [禾(cereal)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A6%BE), it's original meaning is "huske the cereal and put them together", having enough to eat, farmers feel calm.

The sound component of 穩 is 㥯 - I really want to say that, but I can't. 穩  first appeared in 222–589，the existing [Sigillary Script(篆書)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_script) are writen by future generations. So it is very hard to explain it's pronunciation, which is both the part of [Archaic Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese) and the part of [Phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology). I can only say that in Archaic China, 穩 and 隱 and 㥯 may be similar in pronunciation.

Comment: How is it that an accepted answer has a negative vote?